# Java Criteria API Like condition

Tags: java, sql, jpa, sql-like, criteria

I need to build a dynamic query (with optional filtering parameters and conditions) in Java. I decided to go for the Criteria API since it seemed the most flexible approach.

An example of the condition I'm trying to achieve (Mysql perspective):

```
WHERE idClient = X AND ( idChannel = 1 OR idChannel = 2 OR idChannel = 25) AND filter LIKE '%test%'
```

The parameter "criteria" is a List of predicates with the idChannel filters, created as follows:

```
//Filter by channel
for (Channel channel : channels){
   Predicate channelFilter = qb.equal(address.get(AddressBlocked_.idChannel), channel);
   criteria.add(channelFilter);
}
```

The condition I wrote using the Criteria API (Java perspective):

```
Predicate predicate = qb.and(
      //Client filter
      qb.equal(address.get(AddressBlocked_.idClient), idClient),

      //Channel filter
      qb.or(
            criteria.toArray(new Predicate[criteria.size()])
      ),

      //Address filter
      qb.like(address.get(AddressBlocked_.address), "%"+search+"%") 
);
```

Whenever the address filter "search" variable has any value, the list returns null, otherwise the filtering by channels and client works perfect.

I haven't been able to implement a LIKE filtering option in my CriteriaQuery. Any other approach I should be using or tip?

Comment: what does this bit of code do: `address.get(AddressBlocked_.address)`?

Comment: Its the metamodel representation of the database field if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try using an asterisk for your wildcard character as in the following:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html

Comment: Tried using the wildcard * instead of the % as "*"+search with no different result. Still not receiving any data.

Comment: The error was  setting the "search" variable. It included "" characters and filtering never worked. When i got it to work the syntax i tested successfully was "%"+search+"%"